# HSQLDB select shows no data in intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, hsqldb

i have created and rund successul this sql using HSSQLDB (Connection type  Embedded) :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.T1 (name CHAR(25), age INTEGER NOT NULL);
insert into T1 (name, age) values ('lise',99);
insert into T1 (name, age) values ('fred',199);
insert into T1 (name, age) values ('paul',299);
select * from PUBLIC.T1;
```

i'm used to doing a select in jetbrains idea so that i can see the data.

Here with (HSSQLDB Connection type: Embedded) no data is shown to me (scceenshow below).

**Are there none or how can I see them?**

[image]

Connection type with this HSSQLDB is **Embedded** as you could see in the screeshot below:

Connection type: Embedded

[image]

## comparision with sqLite (no problems):

Since I still have the problem that with hssqldb no data is displayed via the IDEA database window, I have tried SqLite once and it does not cause any problems at all (see Screenshot):

[image]

## comparision with HSSQLDB file (no problems):

[image]

Comment: for me it works fine. (https://i.imgur.com/sPjQOyv.png) and you just don't see 'results' tab after query executed? if you expand 'tables' node under 'public' schema will there be 'T1' table?

Comment: @YuriWin your schema looks difference in the console.
i could not choose public here : https://i.imgur.com/XzgqQXd.png . 
Test Connection tells its ok : https://i.imgur.com/xP1k1Rv.png
look like in your screenshot. 
query the select give me still: `[2021-03-09 16:27:37] completed in 7 ms` its different to your screenshot.

Comment: that means database is not introspected. please select your data source and hit 'Refresh' button - at least you should see 'public' schema in the list, just like in your 'hsqldb - file' data source.

Comment: @YuriWin can't get 'public' schema by refresh (Strg+F5), or restart IDEA or (i also tried) File > Invalidate Caches > Restart https://youtu.be/jpVRHQzeMUk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @eh3rrera explains here https://github.com/eh3rrera/minitwit/issues/11#issuecomment-795467775:

"... I'm not sure if IntelliJ can access it, I think it can only be accessed by the Java program that created it.

Unlike an in-memory db, with db in a file, changes are persisted after the app exits, they're saved to the file. ..."